# Prolog compound statement returning multiple variables

Tags: prolog

I'm super new to Prolog, like, my professor assigned us a program and just asked us to watch a couple youtube videos. No lecture.

So anyway, here's the issue:

I'm supposed to create a pharmacist software that looks up drug interactions.

When I enter a specific drug, then Drug-variable, and Interaction-variable, I get the first drug and interaction in the list (of like, 100 drugs that interact with temazepam):

```
?- interacts(temazepam,Drug,Interaction).
Drug = thalidomide,
Interaction = neutropenia .
```

Part 1) How can I get every drug and its interaction from, say, temazepam?

Partial program listed below [because I have 1609 lines of drug interactions listed]:

```
interacts(X,Y,Interaction):-
Drug(X),
Drug(Y),
Interaction.

Interaction:-
Drug(X),
Drug(Y).

interacts(gatifloxacin,zolpidem,attempted_suicide).
interacts(gatifloxacin,zolpidem,insomnia).
interacts(gatifloxacin,warfarin,cardiac_decompensation).
interacts(gatifloxacin,isosorbide-5-mononitrate,arteriosclerotic_heart_disease).
interacts(gatifloxacin,rosiglitazone,hyperglycaemia).
interacts(gatifloxacin,bortezomib,hyperglycaemia).
interacts(gatifloxacin,mometasone,asthma).
interacts(gatifloxacin,cisplatin,hyperglycaemia).
interacts(gatifloxacin,cisplatin,bone_marrow_failure).
interacts(gatifloxacin,montelukast,difficulty_breathing).
interacts(temazepam,thalidomide,neutropenia).
interacts(temazepam,thalidomide,thrombocytopenia).
interacts(temazepam,timolol,drowsiness).
interacts(temazepam,tizanidine,acid_reflux).
interacts(temazepam,tizanidine,heart_attack).
interacts(temazepam,tolterodine,amnesia).
```

Part 2) I need to be able to list an interaction and get back every drug that caused it.

I guess just the side-effect then all drug interactions listed would be better than listing drug1+sideEffect = drug2.

Example:

```
?- interacts(Drug,Drug,amnesia).
```

Part 3) I should be able to enter a single drug, and get everything with interactions and everything with no interactions.

Example:

```
?- interacts(valacyclovir,Drug,Interaction).
Drug = zolpidem,
Interaction = anxiety
```

But for everything

Excuse me for the edits!
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Can I edit this to include two other things this program should be able to do or start a new question for them?

Comment: Just edited to add other requirements. Sorry for any confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in predicate findall/3 for that:

```
drug_allinteractions(Drug,AI) :-
    findall((D,I),interacts(Drug,D,I),AI).
```

The only goal of drug_allinteractions/2 is using findall/3 to query interacts/3 and put its second and third argument into the list `AI` as a tuple `(D,I)`. Example query: Wich interacting drugs with what interaction-effect are known for gatifloxacin?:

```
   ?- drug_allinteractions(gatifloxacin,L).
L = [(zolpidem,attempted_suicide),(zolpidem,insomnia),(warfarin,cardiac_decompensation),(isosorbide-5-mononitrate,arteriosclerotic_heart_disease),(rosiglitazone,hyperglycaemia),(bortezomib,hyperglycaemia),(mometasone,asthma),(cisplatin,hyperglycaemia),(cisplatin,bone_marrow_failure),(montelukast,difficulty_breathing)]
```

Alternatively, if you just want to query interacts/3 and not write a program:

```
   ?- findall((D,I),interacts(gatifloxacin,D,I),AI).
AI = [(zolpidem,attempted_suicide),(zolpidem,insomnia),(warfarin,cardiac_decompensation),(isosorbide-5-mononitrate,arteriosclerotic_heart_disease),(rosiglitazone,hyperglycaemia),(bortezomib,hyperglycaemia),(mometasone,asthma),(cisplatin,hyperglycaemia),(cisplatin,bone_marrow_failure),(montelukast,difficulty_breathing)]
```

As for your added part 2): You can use findall on your original query:

```
   ?- findall((D1,D2),interacts(D1,D2,amnesia),AI).
AI = [(temazepam,tolterodine)]
```

Note, that unlike in your example I wrote two different variables `D1` and `D2` for the drugs, otherwise you are asking which drug has the interaction-effect amnesia with itself.

Considering your added part 3) I'm not entirely sure what you want. Your query reads: "Show me all drugs that interact with valacyclovir plus the associated effect". That is basically the same as your very first query, just for a different drug. You can query for all drugs in the relation interacts/3 interactively without showing the interacting drugs and the effects by:

```
   ?- interacts(D,_,_).
D = gatifloxacin ? ;
...
```

Or query for an entire list without duplicates by using setof/3:

```
   ?- setof(D1,D2^I^interacts(D1,D2,I),AI).
AI = [gatifloxacin,temazepam]
```

If you, however, try to find a list of drugs that are not interacting with a given drug, you can write a predicate, say drug_noninteractingdrug/2...

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).

drug_noninteractingdrug(D,NID) :-
    dif(D,NID),                        % D and NID are different
    setof(D2,D^interacts(D,D2,_),L),   % L ... all drugs interacting with D
    interacts(NID,_,_),                % NID ... drug...
    \+member(NID,L).                   % ... that is not in L
```

... and query this using setof/3:

```
   ?- setof(NID,drug_noninteractingdrug(gatifloxacin,NID),NIDs).
NIDs = [temazepam]
```

With your given minimal example this query of course only yields one drug. Note that you need to include library(lists) for the predicate member/2.

Comment: So the top part is for my prolog program? and the second part of the code I put into swi-prolog? I'm getting this error:
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: drug_allinteractions/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)

Comment: Did I have to specify in your top code snippet that D=Drug and I=Interaction?

Comment: @CamelliaWunderbar: yes drug_allinteractions/2 is your program. You put that into the same file that contains interacts/3 facts, say drugs.pl. Then you start swi-prolog and load the file: `?- [drugs].` Now you can query the predicate. Concerning your 2nd question: No. Because `D` is not the same as `Drug`. And there is no varaiable called `Interaction` in the code, so there is no reason for it to be equal with `I`

Comment: Thanks, I did that but am still getting that error:  ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: drug_allinteractions/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)    How do I define a procedure??

Comment: @CamelliaWunderbar: The error `ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: drug_allinteractions/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)` occurs because your source file is *not* loaded and therefore drug_allinteractions/2 is not known to prolog. If you enter the query `?- [drugs].` you should see a message something like `% cost compiled 0.00 sec, 18 clauses` and `true.` in the line below. Replace drugs by the name you used for the sourcefile.

Comment: Thanks!! You're the best!! Regarding the added part 3, yeah you're right. I got confused with the assignment prompt and what I have to do to make it work.

Comment: For part 3, when I try to look for drugs that cause no interaction, I try: 
32 ?- setof(D1,D2^I^interacts(tolterodine,D2,I),AI).
AI = [_G3871, _G3874, _G3877, _G3880, _G3883, _G3886, _G3889, _G3892, _G3895|...].  But what are those codes?? How can i just get drugs? Thanks so much!!

Comment: @CamelliaWunderbar: The first argument `D1` is the one you want to aggregate in the list `AI` but it does not appear in the goal `interacts(tolterodine,D2,I)`. So you get a list with uninstantiated variables (`_G3871` etc.). As you used a specific drug as first argument of the goal, I assume you want to have solutions for `D2` in the list: `?- setof(D2,I^interacts(temazepam,D2,I),AI).` Note that the list still contains drugs with interactions, the latter are just not listed. You probably have some encoding in interacts/3 for non-interacting drugs. And you need to query that.

Comment: How do I do that? Could I do `?- setof(D1,D2^I^interacts(D1,D2,I),AI).` with "not I"?

Comment: I'm trying negation but not getting a list of non-interacting drugs: 
`?- setof(D2,I^interacts(D1,D2,I),AI), not(setof(D2,I^interacts(gatifloxacin,D2,I),AI)).
D1 = acarbose,
AI = [rosiglitazone, simvastatin] .`

Comment: I'm obviously not understanding the negate statement:

`?- findall((D2),interacts(D1,D2,I),AI),
not(findall((D2),interacts(gatifloxacin,D2,I),AI)).

AI = [zolpidem, zolpidem, warfarin, isosorbide-5-mononitrate, rosiglitazone, bortezomib, mometasone, cisplatin, cisplatin|...].`

Comment: Wow!! You are so awesome!! Much appreciated!!